# What does クる mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, words, slang

> あんた最近避けてるでしょ。何考えてるか知らないけどあんたに変に距離を取られると結構クるのよ、くだらない理由でやってるのなら止めなさいよ

I'm guessing it has a negative meaning, but I look up "kuru" on denshi jisho dictionary and nothing that makes sense in the context pops up. Where do I find this word? Is it slang?

Comment: I believe this「結構クる」can be figuratively understood as "it affects me (psychologically)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This 来る still roughly means "to come (to the speaker)", but its subject can often be some intangible stimulation (e.g., pain, stink, hunger) or strong emotion (e.g., sorrow, anger). In English, perhaps "to strike (me)" or "to come off (to me)" is somewhat close.

> #### 来る
>
> ❽感情・感覚などの作用や反応が生じる。
> 「痛みが去ると空腹感が来た」
> 「喜びの後に悲しみが来る」
> 「『〔肩をもんだときの痛みが〕来ますか？』『結構来ますねえ』」
> 「第六感にぴんと来る」
> 「胸にじんと来る」
> 「がっくりと来る」
> 「かちんと来る」
> 「その意見は僕にはしっくりこないなあ」
> 「今の気分にこんなにぴったり来る音楽はない」
>
> <sub>(Source: 明鏡国語辞典 第三版)</sub>

In your context, what comes is not explicitly stated, but it suggests the speaker is psychologically moved in some way or another. She seems to be acting haughty, so I guess she euphemistically implied つらい or さみしい without saying it directly.

> あんたに変に距離を取られると結構クるのよ
> It's pretty nerve-wracking if you distance yourself from me.